How to properly format CSV output using jq and sed?
I'm trying to process a JSON file and convert it to a CSV format using jq and sed. My goal is to replace decimal points with commas in one of the fields and ensure the output is properly formatted with semicolons as delimiters. However, I'm encountering issues with escaping characters.
My sample input json is this
[
  {
    "Group": "A",
    "Area": "00",
    "Total": "11,76"
  },
  {
    "Group": "A",
    "Area": "00",
    "Total": "11,84"
  },
  {
    "Group": "A",
    "Area": "00",
    "Total": "11,60"
  },
  {
    "Group": "A",
    "Area": "00",
    "Total": "15,98"
  }
]

Here's the jq and sed script I'm using:
json_to_csv() {
    input_file=$1 #json file
    output_file=$2 #csv file

jq -r '
.[] |
.MetaData as $meta |
.Data[] |
[
    ($meta[1].Nombre),  #Group
    ($meta[2].Nombre),  #Area
    (.Valor | tostring | gsub("\\.";"\\,")) #Value
] |
@csv' "$input_file" | 
sed 's/"//g' |  # Remove quotes generated by @csv
sed 's/\\,/,/g' |  # Remove the backslash escaping the comma
sed 's/,/;/g' > "$output_file"  # Replace commas with semicolons

# Add header
sed -i '1iGroup;Area;Total' "$output_file"

    return $?
}


THe output I am getting is:
Group;Area;Total
A;2;11\;76
A;2;11\;84

What i need is:
Group;Area;Total
A;2;11,76
A;2;11,84

I have tried several variants, but I either get all semicolons, all commas, or a escaping bar

Could you add a short sample of your input json?

It would be something like this:
[
{ "Group": "A", "Area": "00", "Total": "11,76" },
{ "Group": "A", "Area": "00", "Total": "11,84" },
{ "Group": "A", "Area": "00", "Total": "11,60" },
{ "Group": "A", "Area": "00", "Total": "15,98" }
]
Really, my problem is that when I tried to change the commas to semicolons, the commas inside the decimals numbers also get changed, or they keep a bar ().

As you have written code that isolates the last ; (with \\;), you can do sed 's/\\;/,/' , but the  jq solution below makes much more sense. Also, to amplify pmf initial comment, you can include multiple substitions in one call to sed, i.e. sed 's/"//g;s/\\,/,/g;s/,/;/g' .You can even include (as the first cmd) your 1i... cmd, but different seds require more or less strict formatting to make that work. AND in the future, when readers ask for sample data, include it in the body of your question, don't extend questions in comments (please (-; ) . Glad you got a solution. Good luck.

This look like an XY Problem! Please, as already suggested by @LéaGris's comment, show us your input! Add more details!!

No need to use sed multiple times. Infact, jq can also handle all of this by itself.
It seems you want to get rid of all CSV escapes, and use semicolons as delimiters. In that case you could use join instead of @csv.
Assuming the following input (from looking at your own attempt), you'd get:
[{
    "MetaData": [
        {"Nombre": ""},
        {"Nombre": "A"},
        {"Nombre": 2}
    ],
    "Data": [
        {"Valor": 11.76},
        {"Valor": 11.84}
    ]
}]

jq -r '
  ["Group","Area","Total"], (.[]
    | .MetaData as $meta | .Data[]
    | [$meta[1,2].Nombre, (.Valor | tostring | sub("\\."; ","))]
  ) | join(";")
'

Group;Area;Total
A;2;11,76
A;2;11,84

Demo

It works! thank you!

It's not jq, but I want to introduce you to another useful tool: it's Miller.
If you run
mlr --j2c sub -f Total "," "." input.json >output.csv

you get
Group,Area,Total
A,00,11.76
A,00,11.84
A,00,11.60
A,00,15.98


--j2c: This option tells Miller to read the input data as JSON and to output as CSV. (In this case it is actually only important that input is interpreted as JSON which supports sub operations on strings.)
sub: This is the Miller verb or command that performs a substring substitution operation.
-f Total: This option, used with the sub verb, specifies which field (column) the substitution will be performed on. In this case, it's the field named Total
",": This is the first argument to the sub command and represents the substring you want to search for. In this case, it is a literal comma character.
".": This is the second argument to the sub command and represents the substring that should replace the found matches

